# Gitlab container registry tag expiration policy not working - regex format? schedule?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying the Gitlab "CI/CD > Container Registry tag expiration policy" setting, and so far it's not deleting anything. We use semantic versioning (with a "v" prepended), and my goal is to automatically delete old "patch" releases:

- Keep all major & minor tags: vM.0.0 and vM.m.0.
- Delete all but a few recent tags matching vM.m.p (where p is not zero)

Given that I'm enabling this new setting on an old project, it's risky to find my answer by experimentation. Even on a new project, experimenting would take a lot of effort and calendar time. A dry-run or preview option would be really nice here, so I could try out the settings without fear of deleting important tags.

I tried the following "expire" regex: `v[1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*[.][1-9][0-9]*`. So far it hasn't had any effect. Which leaves me wondering:

- How often does this run? Do I just need to wait longer?
- Am I mis-understanding the way this setting works?
- Is my regex bad?
- What regex format is expected, even?

  - A more complex example in the UI would be nice. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/214007#note_322637771 mentioned that, but was closed without addressing that point.
- Is there any way to see feedback on this cleanup, like maybe in the project activity log?

My current approach is to tweak this setting once a day, then check my tags list the next day to see if it had any effect.

I'd appreciate general advice for verifying/troubleshooting this setting, and/or specific suggestions for how to match my particular version scheme.

Here's a screenshot of my current settings:

[image: Gitlab CI/CD container expiration policy]

Answer (score 5):

I eventually gave up on this and took a different approach. Probably the most frustrating part was wondering when it runs. Is it once a day at a regular time? A random time each day? Once after every push to the registry? I was never sure how long to wait and see if my settings changes made a difference.

Instead I found an API method that exposes all of the same options. I actually like the API better than a project setting

- I can see more clearly how & when it runs.
- I can see error messages and results.
- I can track the config in git, in .gitlab-ci.yml, rather than having to document a separate project setting.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#delete-registry-repository-tags-in-bulk gives an overview and some example curls. Here's how I added it to my pipeline:

```
# In before_script:
- apk --update add curl

...

# In the job script:
    # Get registry id. Assumptions: valid response, "id" is first field, and project only has one registry.
    - REGISTRY_ID=`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$API_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/registry/repositories" | cut -d, -f1 | cut -f2 -d:`
    - TAGS_URL=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/registry/repositories/$REGISTRY_ID/tags
    - curl --request DELETE --data 'keep_n=10' --data 'older_than=1week' --data "name_regex_delete=v[0-9][.].*" --data "name_regex_keep=.*[.]0" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$API_TOKEN" "$TAGS_URL"
```

Using the API, I was able to quickly figure out which regex patterns worked. It's not immediate, but it seems to take effect within a minute. I'm assuming I could take those same regexes and use them in the project settings, but I'm happier sticking with the API for now.